# Python Stacktrace: calledfuncs dictionary with strange syntax: "Class'>.method"

Tags: python, syntax, stack-trace, trace

When I look at the dictionary generated with:

```
import trace
tracer = trace.Trace(countfuncs=True)
tracer.runfunc(callableObj, *args, **kwargs)
print tracer.results().calledfuncs
```

on one machine (python 1.3) I get a strange syntax for the keys of the printed dictionary;  a key looks like:

```
('/path/to/file.py', 'module', "SomeClass'>.some_method")
```

The thing I wonder about are the characters: '>

On another machine with python 1.3.1 the third tuple-entry looks like expected, without the '> bit.

Have you got an idea where this comes from and why its there on one machine and not on another?

Comment: Look like a python bug :/ Do you have any difference on the class name ? (try print repr(yourobj), and check the output). I suspect a difference of the repr() somewhere, but dunno exactly.

Comment: Wow. Are you a computer archaeologist? 1.3 seems... old.

Comment: Sorry, confused the python version. It's python 2.6.6 on the machine with the strange '> and python 2.7.2+ on the other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't mean Python 2.3?

In trace.py, the classname is calculated from:

```
    ...
        clsname = str(classes[0])
    ...
    if clsname is not None:
        # final hack - module name shows up in str(cls), but we've already
        # computed module name, so remove it
        clsname = clsname.split(".")[1:]
        clsname = ".".join(clsname)
        funcname = "%s.%s" % (clsname, funcname)
```

Usually `str(someclass)` gives you something like `module.klass` so splitting at the dot gives you a clean name for the class. For some reason the class on the system you are looking at is giving a repr that ends with the string you are seeing, so perhaps it was something like `<proxy for 'module.klass'>`.

I would try editing trace.py on that machine to (temporarily) not split the clsname variable and then you might be able to figure out what it should really say.

Comment: Ok, commenting out, the third tuple entry now looks like: "<class 'SomeClass'>.some_method, so things become more clear. But how shall I leave the trace.py?

Comment: I would put trace.py back as it was. Now you know why trace is giving odd output the only thing left is to figure out why you're getting a strange string from the `repr` of the class. Try searching source files for `<class` perhaps?

Comment: The strange string comes from Django. Since I need this running I may need to setup a python 2.7 virtualenv on the machine running 2.6.

Comment: Yes, use `virtualenv` if you have the correct version of Python already on the machine or do a clean build if you need a different version. FWIW, I find http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/buildout/python/ a useful way to get a range of Python versions with virtualenv for each.